# Django: static file image URL paths breaks except for main page template

Tags: javascript, python, django, file, static

I'm trying to setup my static file in development. I have an image located in polls/static/images/banner.jpg. When I navigate to 127.0.0.1:8000/ the banner shows up, but when I go to something like 127.0.0.1:8000/2ndpage the banner breaks.

my index (URL: 127.0.0.1:8000/) template contains:

```
{% include 'polls/header.html' %}
```

The URL for the banner http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/images/banner.jpg

my 2ndpage template also contains:

```
{% include 'polls/header.html' %}
```

But the URL for the banner changes to http://127.0.0.1:8000/2ndpage/images/banner.jpg

my polls/header.html template:

```
<img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/gcs_banner.jpg" />
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url

urlpatterns = patterns('polls.views',
    url(r'^$', 'index'),
    url(r'^2ndpage/$', '2ndindex'))
```

views.py

```
def index(request):
    ...
    return render_to_response('polls/index.html', {'latest_people_list':     latest_people_list,}, context_instance = RequestContext(request))

def 2ndpage(request, people_id):
    ...
    return render_to_response('index/detail.html', {'people': p}, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

Why does the URL change from ../static/.. to ../2ndpage/..? How do I fix this so that when I use     {% include 'polls/header.html' %}    the banner always shows up?

Comment: Please paste your view code for 2ndpage.

Comment: So I found the answer from another question, basically I just need to add context_instance = RequestContext(request)). But I dont understand what this is doing or why I always need to add it. can someone explain in plain terms??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that in the second page, `{{ STATIC_URL }}` **is not defined**. Thus, src ends up with `images/gcs_banner.jpg`. Which is a **relative url because it's not prefixed with a slash**. It is then converted to a absolute path using the current absolute url: **/2ndpage/images/gcs_banner.jpg**.

`{{ STATIC_URL }}` is probably set by a context processor - at least that how it works in my projects. **[Context processors are actually a feature from RequestContext](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django.template.RequestContext)**. When a view returns response **without RequestContext then the context processors are not run**, e.g.:

```
from django import shortcuts 
# ....
    return shortcuts.render_to_response(template_name, context)
```

This is an example of **explicit usage of RequestContext** with [render_to_response()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render-to-response):

```
from django import shortcuts 
from django import template
# ....
    return shortcuts.render_to_response(template_name, context, 
        context_instance=template.RequestContext(request))
```

That said, Django 1.3 provides a better shortcut with **implicit usage of RequestContext**, [render()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render):

```
from django import shortcuts 
# ....
    return shortcuts.render(request, template_name, context)
```

Comment: so the issue was I just needed to add context_instance = RequestContext(request)) but im not really understanding what this does exactly...

Comment: This executes context processors, which set STATIC_URL.