# Django Can't Display The Page That Has Seperate CSS, JS files

Tags: django

I've read some documents related with static files but couldn't make it work.
I'm using runserver on my computer for test purpose. My html is at this directory: C:\mytemplates\polls\t3.html. t3.html uses js and css files that were put under the my_static_files. So what should be the Django static settings, and where should the my_static_files be put?

Comment: It is explained pretty good here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/static-files/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have not specified that exactly, i'm going to assume your static files are  C:\my_static_files\

If so your settings should look like this:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = 'C:\my_static_files\'
```

In your template you can then use the {{STATIC_URL}} to load your static files:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{STATIC_URL}}css/your_style.css" />
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "{{STATIC_URL}}/js/your_script.js"></script>
```

If you have named the subfolders js and css different, change the links accordingly. If it still doesn't work, check and doublecheck your leading and trailing slashes.

As you mentioned that using {{STATIC_URL}} does not return anything, i have to add this: to be able to use {{STATIC_URL}} you have to pass a RequestContext to your template. You can do this when returning a Response from a view by passing it a context_instance like this (ie.):

```
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def some_view(request):
    # your view code here

    return render_to_response(template_name,
                              context, 
                              context_instance=template.RequestContext(request) )
```

Comment: you also need to uncomment `'django.contrib.staticfiles'` in `INSTALLED APPS`

Comment: This didn't work. I did all the settings written above. Console says:

[22/Apr/2012 13:24:27] "GET /t3 HTTP/1.1" 200 3683  
[22/Apr/2012 13:24:27] "GET /iui-0.31/iui.css HTTP/1.1" 404 2885  
[22/Apr/2012 13:24:27] "GET /iui-0.31/iui.js HTTP/1.1" 404 2882  

can it be related to views.py?
when I check the source code of the loaded html I saw that {{STATIC_URL}} is not converted any string.

Comment: You probably need to create a RequestContext to return, as otherwise {{STATIC_URL}} is not passed to the template as a variable. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9543869/django-static-file-image-url-paths-breaks-except-for-main-page-template

Comment: I followed the steps mentioned above, and when i render template i get /static/css/style.css in my source. However this is a 404. I have put my static folder in mysite->mysite->static location. Anything i might be missing?